# Window NSMenu adding extra NSMesnuItems (Swift, macOS)

Tags: swift

I deleted all the menu items from the Window NSMenu except **Minimize** and **Bring All to Front**. However, when I run the app, three more menu items get added: **Move Window to Left Side of Screen**, **Move Window to Right Side of Screen** and **Enter Full Screen**. How do I remove these menu items? Has it got something to do with the attribute inspector of my Window (just a guess)?

For reference:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The Window menu in the object library is predefined. You might create a custom menu.

Comment: @vadian That is pretty clever and simple. Idk why I didn't think of that. However, how do I then implement "Bring All to Front"?

Comment: In the original menu figure out where the menu items are connected to. The target of almost all menu items is First Responder (the red cube in the application scene).

Comment: @vadian thank you so much. You are a godsend. :D